# Get music library files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, known-folders

Trying to excess Music folder on windows phone app 8.1 but getting following Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Here is the code: Calling

```
try
{
    GetFiles();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

private async void GetFiles()
{
    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> listOfFiles;
    if (folder!=null)
    {
        listOfFiles =await folder.GetFilesAsync(); //this line casuing Debugger.break();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the capability in package manifest file

Comment: Try the code i posted. Hope it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Music-library capability in package.appmanifest file

Then try this code. It worked for me

```
    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    if (folder!=null)
    {
       var songs = (await   folder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();
    }
```

[Link to Sample Code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4A5FCCA92E37830!485&authkey=!AB0i24NRHnAQ_Js&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: `private async void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
                if (folder != null)
                {
                    var songs = (await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();
                    Debug.WriteLine("count=" + songs.Count);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("exception while getting files:" + e1.StackTrace);
            }

        }`

Comment: The method or operation is not implemented exception

Comment: In which line? Can you post the stacktrace. I just tried your code,I'm not able to regenerate the exception

Comment: here is stack trace
exception while getting files:   at Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get_MusicLibrary()
   at PhoneApp1.MainPage.<LayoutRoot_Loaded>d__17.MoveNext()

Comment: Sorry,I'm not able to regenerate it.

Comment: Can you give me your c# project ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Works perfect on **Windows 8.1 Universal**

```
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

            var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            try
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                playbackElement3.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);//Play Selected

                playbackElement3.Play();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Then try to get the list from source

Comment: appreciate your code but i do not want to pick file using picker! i want to get file  using KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(); method

Comment: i am sorry to hear that... my bad